# coco2d-x call function with multiple arguments?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm working on a cocos2d-x project and got stuck. I want to call a function, delay and than call the same function again. I'm using cocos2d-x 2.2.5. and developing for Android.

This is what I got so far:

```
CCArray *arr = CCArray::create();
arr->addObject(pSprite);
arr->addObject(pGetal);

CCFiniteTimeAction *fun1 = CCCallFuncO::create(this, callfuncO_selector(GameLayer::animateFlip), arr);
CCDelayTime *delay = CCDelayTime::create(1.0);
pSprite->runAction(CCSequence::create(fun1, delay, fun1, NULL));
```

The method I want to call:

```
void GameLayer::animateFlip(CCObject *pSObj, CCObject *pGObj){

   CCSprite *pSprite = (CCSprite *) pSObj;
   CCLabelTTF *pGetal = (CCLabelTTF *) pSObj;
   ...
   ...
}
```

The function is in the same class and requires two arguments. I've tried putting both arguments (CCSprite and CCLabelTTF) in an array, but it crashes on runtime... 
When I call the function just like this no errors occur:

```
this->animateFlip(sprite1, getal1);
```

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Can't you modify the called function to take only one argument, which would either be a pointer to a `CCarray`, or a pointer to a custom `struct` containing the two objects?

Comment: also, if the c++ behaves similarly to the obj-c version, avoid reusing an action object : they maintain state, and the end state of fun1 may be illegitimate as a start state. create a fun2 object instead.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to CCCallBlock in C++? Something like CCCallLambda perhaps? That would solve the parameter problem since they are already in local scope. Keep in mind that depending on how memory management in cocos2d-x works the CCArray is either never released (leaked) or autoreleased which may happen before the selector runs, hence the crash. An easy workaround would be to temporarily assign the references to member variables, but you'd still have to be careful about memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I've created a struct for my buttons like Joachim suggested, which has the sprite and the label in it. All the buttons are put in an array. I also added the functions animateFlip and showFlip to it. AnimateFlip works fine and I'm able to call the function from the gamelayer for each indevidial button.

```
void GameLayer::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet *pTouches, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

    CCTouch *touch = (CCTouch *)pTouches->anyObject();
    CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        if(butArr[i].sprite->boundingBox().containsPoint(location)){
            butArr[i].animateFlip();
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

The struct:

```
struct Button
{
    cocos2d::CCSprite *sprite;
    cocos2d::CCLabelTTF *getal;
    int getalINT;
    void showFlip();
    void animateFlip();
};
```

But as rule number one in programming tells us, where one problem is solved, two shall arise, I've stumbled upon a new problem:

```
void Button::showFlip()
{
    CCFiniteTimeAction *fun1 = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(Button::animateFlip));
    CCFiniteTimeAction *fun1 = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(Button::animateFlip));
    CCDelayTime *delay = CCDelayTime::create(1.0f);
    this->runAction(CCSequence::create(fun1, delay, fun2, NULL));
}
```

The CCCallFunc::create() request a context (I guess?), which is usually 'this', but 'this' in my struct point to Button. How can I get the context of the gamelayer?

Thanks again!